# Best practice to limit results in get_row()?

Tags: database, query, mysql, wpdb, get-row

This is my query to check if a title exists (it's in a loop, therefore [$i]).

```
$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $titles_arr[$i] . "'", 'ARRAY_A');
```

Anyway, I would like to know how to use `LIMIT 0,1000` to **query only the last 1000 added posts** to the database when using get_row() function.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a `SQL` question. The only possible WordPress related component would be if you were asking about database structure, [which is in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). Or you could just look at the database itself.

The post ID is incremented and never duplicated. The highest `ID`s are the last added. The query is simple.

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
WHERE post_title = '{$titles_arr[$i]}'
ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID DESC
LIMIT 0,1000
```

Please note that I used `$wpdb->posts` instead of hard-coding the table name. Your query will break on a site that has a different prefix than `wp_` and on multisite (I am pretty sure).

Note that the `$wpdb->posts` hold a lot of information besides simply `post` post types. If you specifically want just `post` post types you will need to add a further condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
WHERE post_title = '{$titles_arr[$i]}'
AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID DESC
LIMIT 0,1000
```

Still further conditions could be required to prevent the results from including 'draft' or 'pending' posts, or 'revisions', or a number of other things.

Comment: I don't think this technically answers the question, though it has been accepted. Perhaps asker mis-asked the question, but the criteria *query only the last 1000 added posts* can not be satisfied via `LIMIT`, which only affects the range of the result set, not what is being queried- that would require another `WHERE`.

Comment: @Milo : Another condition to limit to the "post" type? Yes, true. I thought about that, but wasn't sure if that was the intend. I will clarify.

Comment: say you have 1001 posts and only the very first one matches the `post_title`, this query will return that 1 row, when it should return 0 rows according to askers criteria, because it wasn't one of *the last 1000 added posts*.

Comment: @Milo : Ah... Got it. You're right. I'll see what I can do.